# adding an array into an array at a particular position (based on key value) in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, multidimensional-array

I searched a lot, but I could not get a satisfactory answer on the net. In javascript, how do I add an array into another multidimensional array at a particular position based on a key value?

```
finalArray = []; //final result to be stored here
for(var i=0; i<5; ++i)
{
    var temp = [];
    for(var j in $scope.team[i])
    {
        // counter = some value calculated here
        temp[j] = $scope.team[i][j][counter];
    }
    finalArray[group[i]] = temp; // This gives an error
}
```

basically, I have

```
group = [ 'alpha' ,'beta', 'gamma' ]; //this array generated dynamically
```

my finalArray should be like,

```
finalArray['alpha'] = [ some records ];
finalArray['beta'] = [ some records ];
....
```

As far as I know, the way to add array into another array is to use .push() method, but that creates indices as 0, 1, 2... which is not desired. Please help me out

Comment: If you want named keys instead of numeric indexes, then you want to use a Javascript object, not an array.

Comment: Object will work best

Comment: how do I declare it using Object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use Object instead of Array. Make the following changes in the code

```
finalArray = {}; //final result to be stored here
for(var i=0; i<5; ++i)
{
    var temp = {};
    for(var j in $scope.team[i])
    {
        // counter = some value calculated here
        temp[j] = $scope.team[i][j][counter];
    }
    finalArray[group[i]] = temp;
}
console.log(finalArray); //to see the object key value structure
```

now you can reference the values in finalArray with group[i] name. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You have to define your `finalArray` variable as Object instead of and Array:

```
var finalArray = {}; //or better in your case finalMap
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var group = [ 'alpha' ,'beta', 'gamma' ];
var finalArray = {}; //declare it object as you dont want 0,1 indexes
for (var index in group){
    finalArray[group[index]] = "some records/arry of records"
}
console.log(finalArray);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ym1rxabg/)

Comment: you should check `if ( gorup.hasOwnProperty(index) ) {...}` to prevent undesidered behaviour.